# Is any way to override @OrderBy in *ToMany relation?

Tags: doctrine-orm, annotations, doctrine, many-to-many, one-to-many

I have two classes `User` and `Groups`. User has Many To Many relation to Groups.
`User` extends `BaseUser` (which has some mappings) and `Group` extends `BaseGroup`(also with mappings). BaseUser has no `@OrderBy` annotation for Groups. Question is: what is the annotation I should add into User which will allows me to override `@OrderBy`?

PS: `BaseUser` and `BaseGroup` are located in third party's bundle. I unable to edit them